# Redirección con .htaccess a una subcarpeta (App desarrollada en Angular 8)

Tags: angular, .htaccess, aplicación-web, url, filezilla

Tengo un problema con la redirección de mi aplicación, es una aplicación desarrollada en Angular8 y estoy subiendo a un ambiente de prueba el cual esta ubicada en una subcarpeta del dominio, al hacer build la url asignada es ejemplo: https://ambiente.pruebas.com/pruebas/, al subir todo el contenido de la carpeta dist por fileZilla en la subcarpeta /pruebas, me enseña la app pero si refresco la pantalla (f5) entonces me da error 404. El caso curioso es que si a la subcarpeta y url de la index lo llamo https://ambiente.pruebas.com/**test/** si funciona el htaccess con la redirección. 
¿Tienen alguna idea de porque me funciona con una subcarpeta y con las demas no?
comparto el archivo htaccess que estoy usando.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

como ven es un código generico no apunto a un test como tal, por lo tanto no entiendo porque me funciona si se llama test y si no, no. 
Tampoco es nada en el código de la app porque subo versiones distintas a las carpetas para probar y sigue funcionando en test pero no en pruebas.
Otro dato curioso es que si solo pongo una RewriteRule que redireccione a google.com en la carpeta test lo hace sin problemas pero en las demas no, sinceramente no entiendo lo que puede estar pasado. 
Espero haberme explicado bien y que me puedan ayudar.
De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que básicamente el problema que tienes proviene de que estás confundiendo el routing de tu servidor http (apache) con el routing de angular. Revisa el routing de tu aplicación para que puedas resolver el problema https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Hola gracias, ya lo he revisado pero no es eso, igualmente si fuera en router de la app no me funcionara bien en local, y en el local si que funciona perfectamente el problema lo tengo al subirla. Igualmente muchas gracias.